# Retrieve data from multiple tables using their relationships-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table I need to complete,  for now, it has 3 columns DATE, SHIFT and STATION.

I only want the data that is attached to the logged-in user.
I have a pivot table where I can call the data from for DATE and SHIFT, but Stations is a separate table,

My pivot table is to display my many to many relationships between USER and SHIFTS called shift_user. this works,
the STATIONS table relationship is a one to many relationship with USER
as a User will belong to one station,  but a station will have multiple users

**Stations model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

}

**User Model**

```
public function station()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Station');
}
```

**Controller for Project**

```
$user = Auth::user();

    return view('layouts/timesheet/index', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

**Blade view to get info into tables**

```
                <table class="table table-sm table-success">

            <tr>
                <th scope="col">DATE/DAY</th>
                <th scope="col">SHIFT</th>
                <th scope="col">STATION</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody class="table-light">

                @foreach ($user->Station as $station)
                @endforeach
                @foreach ($user->shifts as $shift)

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $shift->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $shift->Name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $station->Name }}</td>

                    </tr>


                @endforeach
```

Here is a picture of the table I want to fill in. I want the Station name to display, but I just get this ID which I think is the user I.D

[image: Table to complete]

Please can you let me know what  I can do to call the data from another table via the relationship?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you create a function that's same as when you call it on Blade View.

**Station.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function stations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Station');
}
```

Then on blade view, try this:

```
@foreach($user as $u)
  <tr>
       <td>{{ $u->shift->created_at }}</td>
       <td>{{ $u->shift->Name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $u->stations->name }}</td>    // I assume the column in stations table is "name"
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I now get this error :(  .... Attempt to read property "shifts" on bool

Comment: Ive done it, just needed to add this to my controller and I could then call the data from two tables, Thank you for your response, I am grateful.  $user = Auth::user();
        $station = $user->Station;

Comment: and the model still the same? i mean that One to Many relationship function?

Comment: Yes, I haven't had to really change the models, I've kept them as what I posted originally, but I have added the foreign keys in for each model, I don't know if that made any difference, but it works, so ill leave them in :)